# Class diagram count options and add options

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a **class diagram** for a menu.

[image: class diagram]

How do I know how many menu options there are available (menu items), and how do I add more.

I was thinking since its `0..*` it should be initially 0, but you could add up to an N amount.

Comment: The class diagram answers all your questions. Are you having trouble understanding the diagram?

Comment: `0..*` means any positive number greater or equal to zero. So that's the number of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicity `0..*` tells you that an instance of a `Menu` can have between 0 and unlimited number of `MenuItem`.

The class-diagram makes general statements about your classes.  It does not tell anything about specific moments in time, chronology, nor behavior.

The `Menu` constructor is not specified.  We may suppose that a new `Menu` starts with no items.  But we don't know for sure:  there could well be a constructor to which one or several items are provided as argument right from the start.

From its name, we can guess that the `Menu` operation `AddItem()` adds new items to a menu.  From its arguments, we can guess that AddItem() construct those items to be added.

***Not related:** the constructor `MenuItem()` should be preceded by `«Create»`.  But most readers would guess the meaning.*